# How to save a 3D image or what's the image format that we can spin it manually after saving it from Matlab without opening Matlab?

Tags: matlab, visualization

I have plotted a 3-dimension figure which is the 3-D cloud water content from a Cloud Resolving Model. I would like to save it and preserve the image information that I can rotate it along different direction after I have saved it. I know it's possible to save it as format fig in Matlab and do what I want only using Matlab to open it. Is any other format of image that can do the same thing with open Matlab?

Actually I am not familiar with this part and not sure what's key word is more about this question.

Comment: `pdf` can display full 3D images. But I'm not sure Matlab can do same export as CADs can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Export figure to 3D interactive PDF](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/37640-export-figure-to-3d-interactive-pdf)

using this plugin it is possible to save a 3d figure as a U3D file and embed it into a pdf

Comment: I found this Matlab tool last night! 
But there are some bugs...  After I tried to fix some of these bugs, I still get this message 
"Error using idtf2u3d (line 75) IDTFConverter executable returned with error."
--
I am not sure how to figure this problem out....